# WebGl - Oblique projection

Tags: javascript, html, matrix, webgl

I am trying to implement an oblique projection in WebGL and something is not working out: the projection looks just like ortho.

This is the code setting up the projection matrix:

```
    mat4.identityMatrix(pMatrix);
    var m = mat4.createMatrix();
    var n = mat4.createMatrix();
    m = mat4.oblique(pMatrix, 15, 60);  
    n = mat4.ortho(-2.0, 2.0, -2.0, 2.0, 0.1, 100, pMatrix);
    pMatrix = mat4.matrixMultiply(m, n);
```

I have also tried:

```
mat4.identityMatrix(pMatrix);
mat4.shearMatrix(pMatrix, degreesToRadians(15), [1, 0, 0]);
mat4.shearMatrix(pMatrix, degreesToRadians(60), [0, 1, 0]);
mat4.ortho(-2.0, 2.0, -2.0, 2.0, 0.1, 100, pMatrix);
```

The shear matrices work fine, but the combination of the two shears only give an ortho view, as does the first example.

The matrices are:

```
mat4.oblique = function(pMtrx, theta, phi){     
    if(!pMtrx){
        pMtrx = mat4.createMatrix();
    }    
    var t = degreesToRadians(theta);
    var p = degreesToRadians(phi);
    var cotT = -1/Math.tan(t);
    var cotP = -1/Math.tan(p);

    pMtrx[0] = 1;
    pMtrx[1] = 0;
    pMtrx[2] = cotT;
    pMtrx[3] = 0;
    pMtrx[4] = 0;
    pMtrx[5] = 1;
    pMtrx[6] = cotP;
    pMtrx[7] = 0;
    pMtrx[8] = 0;
    pMtrx[9] = 0;
    pMtrx[10] = 1;
    pMtrx[11] = 0;
    pMtrx[12] = 0
    pMtrx[13] = 0
    pMtrx[14] = 0
    pMtrx[15] = 1;

    mat4.transpose(pMtrx);

    return pMtrx;   
}

mat4.ortho = function(left, right, bottom, top, near, far, pMtrx){
    if(!pMatrix){
        pMatrix = mat4.createMatrix();
    }
    var a = right - left;
    b = top - bottom;
    c = far - near;

    pMtrx[0] = 2/a;
    pMtrx[1] = 0;
    pMtrx[2] = 0;
    pMtrx[3] = 0;
    pMtrx[4] = 0;
    pMtrx[5] = 2/b;
    pMtrx[6] = 0;
    pMtrx[7] = 0;
    pMtrx[8] = 0;
    pMtrx[9] = 0;
    pMtrx[10] = -2/c;
    pMtrx[11] = 0;
    pMtrx[12] = -1*(left + right)/a;
    pMtrx[13] = -1*(top + bottom)/b;
    pMtrx[14] = -1*(far + near )/c;
    pMtrx[15] = 1;

    return pMtrx;
    };
```

I have been up and down with this one, and can't see where I am going wrong. Advice would be much appreciated.
  This full code verion can be found here: https://gist.github.com/Carla-de-Beer/b935da9a7317f8444495

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the code you posted: `oblique` and `ortho` functions just **set and return** the given matrix. They're **not** taking previous transforms into account and they're **not** returning a new matrix.

So you're overwriting your previous transforms and store references to the same matrix within your `m` and `n` variables.

```
var oblique = mat4.createMatrix();
var orhto = mat4.createMatrix();
mat4.oblique(oblique, 15, 60);  
mat4.ortho(-2.0, 2.0, -2.0, 2.0, 0.1, 100, orhto);
var pMatrix = mat4.matrixMultiply(oblique, ortho);
```

Comment: Thank you. I have tried this before and it did not work. I suspect there migth be an issue with my matrix multiplication matrix. In the end I got round the issue by making a custom-made oblique function. That worked.